# Conjecture: any two sequences of polygonal numbers will share multiple terms between them

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, diophantine-equations

The following conjecture is about polygonal number sequences:

For every $r\ge{3},s\ge{3} \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist $m\ge{2},n\ge{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\frac{n^{2}(r-2)-n(r-4)}{2}\\=\frac{m^{2}(s-2)-m(s-4)}{2}$$

In other words, all sequences of polygonal numbers share some of their terms with each of the others, but not the same ones, obviously. This has already been shown in specific cases such as 36, which is both a square and a triangular number:

$$36=\frac{8(9)}{2}=6^2$$

The conjecture above appears to hold true in every case in which it is tested, but how would I prove it? Has it already been proven? If it's not true for some case, how would I disprove it? I am looking for a non-trivial proof.

Comment: Must be equivalent to some Pell equation.

Comment: @IvanNeretin It is much easier. We can take $m=n=1$ always. If you allow $0$ as natural number, $m=n=0$ is also possible.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I guess I was thinking about having _infinitely many_ terms in common, which might still be true, but not in all cases.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Check my edits.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Check my edits.

Comment: My first comment still stands true. I believe you'll have infinitely many common terms, unless the ratio $r-2\over s-2$ is a square, in which case things become complicated.

Comment: But how do I prove it for the general case?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Infinite cases doesn't exclude "at least one," does it?

Comment: On the contrary, they include that one.

Comment: Just exercising a bit of mathematical caution, that's all...

Answer (score 3):

The conjecture is false.

Take $(r,s)=(14,5)$. Suppose that there exist $m\ge 2,n\ge 2\in\mathbb N$ such that

$$3m^2-m-12n^2+10n=0$$
which implies
$$m=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{144n^2-120n+1}}{6}$$

There has to exist a non-negative integer $t$ such that 
$$144n^2-120n+1=t^2$$
which implies
$$\begin{align}&(12n-5)^2-t^2=24
\\\\&\implies (12n-5-t)(12n-5+t)=24
\\\\&\implies (12n-5-t,12n-5+t)=(2,12),(4,6),(-12,-2),(-6,-4)
\\\\&\implies (n,t)=(1,5),\left(\frac 56,1\right),\left(-\frac 16,5\right),(0,1)\end{align}$$
which contradicts that $n\ge 2\in\mathbb N$.

---

**Added** : There are many counterexamples.

Take $(r,s)=(16p+6,4p+3)$ where $p\ge 5$ is a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime).

Suppose that there exist $m\ge 2,n\ge 2\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$(4p+1)m^2-(4p-1)m+(-16p-4)n^2+(16p+2)n=0$$
which implies
$$m=\frac{4p-1\pm\sqrt{16(4p+1)^2n^2+8(4p+1)(-8p-1)n+(4p-1)^2}}{2(4p+1)}$$

There has to exist a non-negative integer $t$ such that
$$16(4p+1)^2n^2+8(4p+1)(-8p-1)n+(4p-1)^2=t^2$$
which can be written as
$$((16p+4)n-8p-1+t)((16p+4)n-8p-1-t)=24p(2p+1)$$
Since both $p$ and $2p+1$ are odd primes, we get
$$((16p+4)n-8p-1+t,(16p+4)n-8p-1-t)$$
$$=(12p(2p+1),2),(6p(2p+1),4), (4p(2p+1),6),(2p(2p+1),12),$$
$$(12(2p+1),2p),(6(2p+1),4p),(12p,2(2p+1)),(4(2p+1),6p)$$
implying
$$n=\frac{6p^2+7p+1}{4p+2},\frac{6p^2+11p+3}{16p+4},\frac{2p^2+5p+2}{8p+2},$$
$$\frac{2p^2+9p+7}{16p+4},\frac{21p+7}{16p+4},1,\frac{8p+1}{8p+2},\frac{15p+3}{16p+4}$$
Considering $16n$, we have
$$16n=\frac{48p^2+56p+8}{2p+1},\frac{24p^2+44p+12}{4p+1},\frac{16p^2+40p+16}{4p+1},$$
$$\frac{8p^2+36p+28}{4p+1},\frac{84p+28}{4p+1},16,\frac{128p+16}{8p+2},\frac{240p+48}{16p+4},$$
i.e.
$$16n=24p+16-\frac{8}{2p+1},6p+9+\frac{2p+3}{4p+1},4p+9+\frac{7}{4p+1},$$
$$2p+8+\frac{2p+20}{4p+1},21+\frac{7}{4p+1},16,16-\frac{8}{4p+1},15-\frac{3}{4p+1}$$
This contradicts that $n\ge 2\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes, in fact it turns out there is more than one counterexample. Wikipedia mentions 10 and 4; no decagonal number is a perfect square except 1.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink: There are many counterexamples. See what I added in the answer.